# Ajax - For loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Ajax calls an array of four strings, I then want to print each string to a new line. 
I have this code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var obj;
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
                document.createTextNode(obj[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "verify.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

However, it doesn't work. `obj.length` returns `4`, I don't know whether the loop isn't executing, or if I can't access the DOM? I'm very new to Javascript and DOM scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work?"

Comment: You're creating text nodes but you're not putting them anywhere?  I suppose you expect them to appear.. somewhere.

Comment: it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: shouldn't it apply them to the body by default?

Comment: @bobster no, newly created nodes are "orphans" - they still have to be put into the tree to become visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually put the nodes into the document.

```
var node;
for (var i = 0, n = obj.length; i < n; i++) {  // NB: not <=
    node = document.createTextNode(obj[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(node);

    node = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I must be rushing things. This is the answer.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as an answer. You'll find a check mark right next to the voting arrows on this post.

Comment: Need to wait 5 minutes apparantly, will do then!

Answer (score 2):

This only creates the textNode, you must still apply it to the DOM somehwere via appendChild:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode